# Difference in query strings; Colon or Question Mark

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to connect to an API (that I did not write) and do a GET. In some of the API, the query string looks like this:

`/api/map?mapId=1234`

But what this particular request is expecting, is this:

`/api/map/:mapId=1234`

This is easily done in Postman, but I'm trying to translate this into jQuery. I'm using jQuery for the other more simple requests; not using it is an option, but I'd need to be pointed in the direction of what to use to accomplish this. Is there a way to tell jQuery to NOT use a question mark and instead use a colon?

Comment: I'm not sure that's a valid URL. Usually, if you have `:` it's to separate the protocol (e.g., `http:` and potentially the port (e.g., `localhost:8080`). It's certainly not a valid way to produce a query string, either.

Comment: Are you sure that it ain't `/api/map/1234`? I would read that syntax as a template/description for the route with parameter and default value.